# making 'true' value in logical vector unique

Tags: r

I've got a seemingly simple problem, but i can't seem to find a good solution for it.

I have a logical vector, like this:

```
vector = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

I want that vector to contain only one TRUE value. So one of them needs to be turned into FALSE. I don't want to do it manually because this is part of a loop. Usually, in the loop the logical vector that is generated will contain only one TRUE value. Sometimes it generates two or more, and if that happens i want to "remove" the other TRUE values.

I tried this:

```
if(length(which(vector)) > 1) {
    for(j in 1:(length(which(vector)) - 1)) {
      which(vector)[j] <- FALSE
    }
  }
```

but then i get an error: `Error in which(vector) <- '*vtmp*' : could not find function "which<-"`

Comment: `replace(vector, which(vector)[-1], FALSE)`

Comment: or `replace(vector, -which.max(vector), FALSE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option

```
vector & cumsum(vector) <2
```

Answer (score 3):

`which.max(x)` will give you the index of the first `TRUE` value, you can assign `FALSE` to the others

```r
x = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
x[-which.max(x)] <- FALSE
x
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem with this:

```
vector[vector == TRUE][2:length(vector[vector == TRUE])] = FALSE
```

In this code you assign to FALSE all the TRUE except the first one. In this other code you assign to FALSE all the TRUE except the last one:

```
vector[vector == TRUE][1:(length(vector[vector == TRUE])-1)] = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way which keeps the first TRUE value and makes the rest FALSE:

```r
s=0
for(i in 1:length(vector)) {  
  if(s==1){
    vector[i]=FALSE
  } 
  if(vector[i]) s=1 
  }
```